# Trying to change model data inside the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a price property in my model that I want to change if a customer selects a different option and I have included my code below. I want to permanently change the data in the model and I have tried a couple of different methods but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. When I try to access the model data when the page posts, the price property stays at the original value. Can anyone help me understand why my code isn't working?

Controller:

```
public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValues)
    {
        // check for urgency first since that is the base price
        if (dropdownValues.urgency != null)
        {
            currentPrice = getUrgencyPrice(dropdownValues.urgency);

            if (dropdownValues.documentType != null)
            {
                currentPrice = currentPrice + getDocumentTypeFee(dropdownValues.documentType);

                if (dropdownValues.numberOfPages != null)
                {
                    currentPrice = currentPrice * Convert.ToInt16(dropdownValues.numberOfPages);
                }
            }
        }

        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return Json(new { currentPrice = currentPrice.ToString("C"), unformattedCurrentPrice = currentPrice.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(HomeworkHelpers.Models.Order c)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        return View("Index", c);
    }
```

View:

```
@model HomeworkHelpers.Models.Order

$('#urgencyList').change(function () {
            var modelData = {
                documentType: $("#documentTypeList").val(),
                urgency: $("#urgencyList").val(),
                numberOfPages: $("#numberOfPagesList").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: modelData,
                url: "/Home/getNewPrice",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#priceLabel').html(data.currentPrice);
                    $('#Price').val(data.unformattedCurrectPrice);
                }
            });
        });

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="row">
    <h2 id="priceLabel">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
    </h2>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UnFormattedPrice)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Price)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</div>
}
```

Model:

```
 namespace HomeworkHelpers.Models
{
public class Order
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string UnFormattedPrice { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: how you are calling this method? Ajax call? if so, you should update the form fields in the ajax call function

Comment: This code does not make sense. Does `modelData` contain property `Price`? What do you think `ModelState.Remove()`, `ModelState.Add()` and `ModelState.SetModelValue()` are doing? You are not returning the model so its pointless.

Comment: @HadiHassan I'm calling this method using an ajax call and I pasted it above. Do you mean changing it in the ajax callback?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using the ajax call to get values of items on the page then return the price for display to the user but I also want to change the price in the model itself

Comment: Try adding `alert(data.currentPrice);` in the success callback, do you get the alert with the correct price?

Comment: @ekad Yes the method does work and displays the correct price. I am trying to then change the price value in the model to the new price I calculated

Comment: In what model? if `modelData` contained property `Price` then its just `modelData.Price = currentPrice;` but you dont seem to be saving the model so any change is immediately lost as soon as the method returns.

Comment: I apologize for not being able to properly explain how my code is supposed to work. I'm learning much of this mvc code as I go. Before this I have only programmed with non website programming. I'm trying to update the model that the view is connected to.

Comment: @user3610374 try $('#priceLabel').val(data.currentPrice); instead of html, it works?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my code to better show the relation between my different parts of code

Comment: @HadiHassan That code works fine. In my code I'm setting the new price to a label so the user sees the new price but at the same time I also want to update the price that the model contains. I'm trying to explain as best as I can everybody :(

Comment: @user3610374 ok i got you now, you should define a hidden field to store the new price also in order to return it back to the controller when you do submit

Comment: If your wanting to update the `Price` property in the view so that you can later submit the form and save it, the just update the value in the DOM. What is the control you have rendered for property `Price`? For example, if you used `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Price)`, then in the success callback it would be `$('#Price').val(data.currentPrice);`

Comment: @HadiHassan I actually tried that as well. I will update to include the hidden portion. That was one of many attempts to get it to work but that value is showing up as null when I try it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the code to show you how I have created the controls to show the current price to the user and the hidden price I attempted to save to the model

Comment: @user3610374. There is no reason to have property `UnFormattedPrice`. Just use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Price)` and then `$('#Price').val(data.currentPrice);` to update the value, which will then post back. If its not, then show your POST method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed my code to what you suggested but it didn't change anything after it did the post back. I updated to show the post method

Comment: Your POST method does not save the data anywhere. Inspect the value of `c.Price` in the method. It will be the value of the updated price.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I inserted a breakpoint and the value of c.Price stayed the same :(

Comment: Your view does not show a `<form>` element but i assume you have one and the hidden input is in it. If the `#priceLabel` is updating then so should the hidden input. You need to debug your code, both server and client side scripts to see what is happening.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated to show it. I was trying to make my code easier to read so sorry about that.

Comment: Try adding `alert(data.unformattedCurrectPrice);` in the success callback, what do you see in the alert?

Comment: @ekad oh I believe I know what was causing it to fail. I formatted the text to show the currency symbol and it was because of that that kept it from saving properly. Someone please post an answer and I will mark it